# MSSQL-Column calculated with two tables, is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have an immense doubt, is it possible to create a column calculated using two tables?

```
Table 1:
---------------------
id  |  Value1 | 
---------------------
1   |    25   |



 Table 2
---------------------
 id  |  Value2 | 
---------------------
 1   |    5    |
```

Now, in a 3rd table I want a calculated column of the values ​​1 and 2?? is it possible?

```
Table 3
    ---------------------
     id  |  Sumvalues | 
    ---------------------
     1   |      ?     |
```

**or is there another method that can be used for "sumvalues" to self-adjust with the change of the other fields related to it?**

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, except maybe via a trigger, but why do you need this?

Comment: I have an Excel file that sum two values ​​of 2 different sheets on a third sheet, and I asked myself how I could do it in mssql or if it was possible to do something similary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to create a view in my opinion:

```
create view vMyView as
select T1.id,
       T1.Value1 + T2.Value2
from [Table1] T1 join [Table2] T2 on T1.id = T2.id
```

This way, everytime you execute query against the view, you will get most actual data.

Comment: and that could be inserted in a third table and updated with a trigger when value1 and value2 is updated .. I've thought about that and I tried it and it works, my question is if you can do a calculated column that does that, it's just out of curiosity . I do not know the limits of SQL

Comment: If I understood correctly: only in view you can create such column. Also, please accept the answer if it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use for adding value1 to value2:

```
SET @value1 = SELECT value1 FROM TABLE1;
SET @value2 = SELECT value2 FROM TABLE2;
SET @value3 = @value1+@value2; 
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (value3) VALUES (@value3);
```

This may contain typos since I’m writting from a cell phone.

Comment: I already tried it and it works, my question is if you can do a calculated column that does that, it's just out of curiosity . I do not know the limits of SQL,  
thank you for your suggestion!